# passing variable between button and sub vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

hello i am trying to pass parameters from asp LinkButton to a sub routine and it doesn't work

this is  the linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkId" OnClick="doSomething(10)">ID
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is my sub

```
   Public Sub doSomething(ByVal mon As Integer)
      MsgBox("this is the number : " & mon)
   End Sub
```

can some one tell me how can we make this work in VB.net

Comment: you need to specify the sender and event arguments, go look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247488/asplinkbutton-not-functioning-in-production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `CommandArgument` property

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkId" OnClick="doSomething"
    CommandArgument="10">ID</asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
  Public Sub doSomething(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Dim btn As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton )
      Dim msg As String = "this is the number : " & Int32.Parse(btn.CommandArgument)
  End Sub
```

Comment: this works fine , but is there is any way easier cause i don't really understand what you just did ... a way to call it like function(par) what if i have more than one parameter how do you do this

Comment: @user1410185: unfortunately you can't do in easier. If you have more than 1 parameter you could do something ugly like having a comma separated string contained different values `CommandArgument="10,mysecondparameter"`. Then you'd have to split the string on the server

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Sorry for the last rollbacked edit, i thought that the CommandArgument property returns object instead of string(like [CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument.aspx)).

Comment: WAWW i though vb is easier than this

Comment: @user1410185: things will be easier when you get used to it :)

Comment: well the problem is when you ask a question there is like millions of ways to do it ... which makes you very confused ha we will see :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass anything directly to an event handler. But you can use `LinkButton`'s [`CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx) property:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
       ID="linkId" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click"
       CommandArgument="10">ID
</asp:LinkButton>
```

in your codebehind (with the correct signature for this event):

```
Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     Dim lb = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
     Dim ID As String = lb.CommandArgument;
End Sub
```

Note that you should not use a MessageBox in an ASP.NET environment since it would be shown on the server and not in the browser.

Comment: thanks Tim but what if i need to send more than one parameter ?

Comment: @user1410185: What could that be? What can be on the client that is not on the server? Normally you only need an identifier which you can pass per id. If you did something on clientside via javascript and you want to persist it, use a HiddenField with runat=server, then you can access it also on serverside.

Comment: how do I pass a variable x to be value of CommandArgument. my control is not databound?

Comment: Ask a real question on stackoverflow, include all necessary informations like your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the DirectCast method.  It may make more sense for your sub to look like this:

```
Public Sub doSomething(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
  Dim msg As String = "this is the number : " & e.CommandArgument
End Sub
```

You can also store a second value in the CommandName property of the control and use it the same way.

edit: With a slight change to your control, use OnCommand instead of OnClick:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkId" OnCommand="doSomething"
CommandArgument="10" Text="ID" />
```